# Is there a way to find out the number of lines from a command output?

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting

I am trying to compare command outputs between two servers. I want to find out the number of lines from the output of commands such as `ls -l`. Is there a way to do so? So far I have not found anything.

Comment: Depends on what you are compairing. `diff /dir1 /dir2` will show the differneces. If there is no output they are the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For someone this may be easier to remember:

`ls -l | grep . -c`

Please note both grep and wc will count auxiliary lines like `total 32044` or or `./dirname:`. To avoid this especially in recursive output like `ls -lR` try this:

`find . -type f | grep . -c`

where first `.` is the directory path and `-type f` means that `find` will list files only. If you need all types (including directories, sockets etc) then just omit  `-type f`.

Please note: `wc -l` DOES count empty lines (just '\n') whilst `grep . -c` - does NOT.

Comment: `grep -c '^'` counts empty lines.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `wc`:

```
$ wc -l .emacs.d/init.el 
73 .emacs.d/init.el
```

From `man wc`:

```
NAME
       wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file

SYNOPSIS
       wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...
       wc [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
       ....
       -l, --lines
              print the newline counts
```

`wc` is part of `GNU coreutils`, you can have it in most `Unix-like` system.

Comment: Note that `wc -l` really counts newline characters, as the manpage says! If your input doesn't end in a newline, the last line will not count. Example (`echo` from `bash` suppresses the trailing newline with `-n`): `echo -n "foobar" | wc -l` results in `0`.

Comment: @Dubu: Yes, we all know that according to `man wc`.

Answer (score 4):

you can pipe your command to `wc` command:

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you could find  number of lines from the output of `ls -l` through `awk` command also,

```
ls -l | awk 'END{print NR}'
```

Awk's NR variable stores the last record number at the end(*After reading all the input lines*).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare a count of the files processed by either server then you can do that reliably like:

```
ls -aR1qp ./ | grep -cv '/\|^$'
```

That recursively lists all files - not directories - one per line including `.dotfiles` beneath the current directory using shell globs as necessary to replace non-printable characters. `grep` filters out any parent directory listings or `..` or `*/` or blank lines - so there should only be one line per file - the total count of which `grep` returns to you. If you want child directories included as well do:

```
ls -aR1qp ./ | grep -cv '^\.\{1,2\}/\|^$'
```

or...

```
ls -AR1q ./ | grep -cv '/\|^$'
```

Note that the `-A` option to `ls` is POSIX as of the latest version.